# Pinax over google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am building web application using Django-nonrel over google app engine.I want to add social networking type of application to my web application. I come to know that Pinax is something that I can use. But is this supported over google app engine ? If no, what is the alternative approach I can take ?
Thank you,
Sunil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Pinax will not run on App Engine out of the box due to underlying incompatibility with the datastore. There is a project to add support [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/tbrander/pinaxcombo/). Related discussions [here](http://groups.google.com/group/pinax-users/browse_thread/thread/dcff1346ddfe54e5), [here](http://groups.google.com/group/pinax-users/browse_thread/thread/2921d3355e4cfaaa), and [here](http://www.clusterify.com/projects/list/dartdog/49/).